# gnuplot terminal x11 scrolling

Tags: scroll, gnuplot, x11

In gnuplot I am using terminal x11. When the size is bigger than the screen, is it possible to add horizontal and/or vertical scroll bars to view the graph? Is there any other terminal type that will let me do that?
Thank you.
Girish

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you want to hear: as far as I know, there is no scrollbar in interactive terminals for graphs that are larger than your screen. At least, I don't see and don't know how to activate one for `wxt` and `qt` terminals.
The only (non-interactive) way I see is to use, e.g. `pngcairo`, `svg` or `pdfcairo` output and scroll your graph in the external PNG-, SVG- or PDF-viewer.

Maybe you want to file a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/)?